# Spades - how to bid my spades suit?

Tags: bidding, spades

In the game of Spades, what is the best or popular practice to bid the ♠ suit? That is to say, how to estimate the number of tricks my spades suit can take?

I calculate my takes in the spades suit by considering those three factors:

1. **High spades** - {A,Kx,Qxx,Jxxx} where x are spades cards used as protection.
2. **Long spades suit** - count each spade beyond the 4th, some count the 4th spade as a "half a take" which combined with other factors might be a take.
3. **Short sides suits + spare spades**

- Void and 1/2/3 spare spades is 1/~1.5/~2.25 takes.
- Singleton and 1/2 spare spades is ~1/~1.5 takes.
- Doubleton and 1 spare spade is a bit less than 1 take.

Note: do not count the same card twice.  Each card should be count once where it produce the maximal value.

Comment: What do you mean by "*is a take*"? Also, since half cards don't exist, please expand on how you calculate the net of actual spades in excess of 3.5.

Comment: "is a take" means count this card as a take (increase your bid by 1).   I count the forth spade as a half a take, so If I also have other "half" takes such as side suit queens or side suits doubletons it will sum up to a take.

Comment: Great! That would be worthwhile to add to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method of adding **[Spade-Length] - 3.5** seems reasonable, except I would halve that whenever partner has already made a bid of 4 or higher. Any bid in excess of 3 is very likely to include Spade length, and it is desirable to avoid double-counting that asset.

Even when partner's bid above 3 is solely based on high card strength, that reduces the value of extra Spades in your own hand as you will be attempting to not ruff those assets.

Also, I believe a refinement of the *Spades' tricks estimate* should consider the presence or absence of a void/singleton in one's hand. Balanced holdings around the table reduce the likelihood of *ruffing tricks*, while unbalanced holdings increase their likelihood. I'm not yet sure how I would do that.

---

Here is [a table of all the hand pattern probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge_probabilities#Hand_pattern_probabilities), with the top few (covering nearly 85% of possibilities) excerpted below.
[image]

Note that the 4333 pattern is only the fifth most common hand pattern, and the most common is 4432 at over 21%. If we take the 4432 pattern as *standard*, then we can rank the most common patterns as being either *stronger* or *weaker* than the standard (in ascending order of estimated strength:

- **Distinctly Weaker**: Estimates from Contract Bridge analysis suggest at east 0.25 trick weaker

  - 4333 HPS = 2(4-5) + (3-3) = -2
- **Standard**:

  - 4432 HPS = 2(4-5) + (4-2) =  0
  - 5332 HPS = 2(5-5) + (3-2) =  1
- **Stronger**: Estimates from Bridge analysis suggests at least 0.25 tricks stronger than average

  - 5422 HPS = 2(5-5) + (4-2) =  2
  - 6322 HPS = 2(6-5) + (3-2) =  3
  - 5431 HPS = 2(5-5) + (4-1) =  3
- **Distinctly Stronger**: Estimates from Bridge analysis suggest at least 0.5 tricks stronger than average.

  - 6331 HPS = 2(6-5) + (3-1) =  4
  - 6421 HPS = 2(6-5) + (4-1) =  5

In this context **stronger** should be interpreted as *more capable of implementing the desired strategy*.  A 6421 hand with short Spades and all its high cards, even if Aces, in the two long suits might be very capable of successfully bidding **Nil**. Obviously the placement of a hand's high cards is of import as well, as an additional refinement.

Also, these estimates are *a priori* - before trumps have been established. Clearly a long trump holding (Spades playing Spades) is even more valuable than shown here for *winning* tricks - but is less able to *lose* tricks.

One numerical estimate of *Hand Pattern Strength* would be to take double the excess of the length of the longest suit over 5, plus the excess of the second longest suit over the shortest suit. I have marked this value as *HPS* for the hand patterns above.

---

My first attempt at a comprehensive hand evaluation for **Spades** would be the sum of:

- [Culbertson Honour Tricks](http://bridgesqueezescomplete.com/bridge/320.html);
  [image]
- HPS (as above) / 4; and
- (Spades length - 4) / 2.

That could be further refined, with experience, by adjusting the denominators for the second and third components for HPS and Spades length. When contemplating a **Nil** bid, consider subtracting the HPS term instead of adding it to the sum.

Comment: Halving could result in 1/4 bids, which surely don't exist!

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: It's called *rounding*. The 4th and 5th cards ( (0.5 + 1.0) / 2 ) become an estimated trick, as do the 6th and 7th ( (1 + 1) / 2 ) when both held.